# Calling a number of files from a folder with fetch_file

Tags: python

I'm  running below code in python to load images from a folder.but every time I run it I get this error"list index out of range" .there are 25 folders in a folder which I'm trying to call.

```
img_names = fetch_files('./*')

imgname = img_names[25]

print(imgname)
```

The error is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-25-0cb2940e3ae1> in <module>

      1 img_names = fetch_files('./*')

----> 2 imgname = img_names[6]
      3 
      4 
      5 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You also say there are 25 folders in the folder. Folders or files? What does you function return?

Comment: error is because of second line:imgname=img_names[25].I get nothing from first line

Comment: Change your code to have `for imgname in img_names` instead of `imgname = img_names[25]` (or `imgname = img_names[6]` and indent the `print`  so its in the loop?

Comment: If there are 25 folders, you can index 0 upto 24. But you have also posted code calling index 6, which then has the error.

Comment: Hello, please include your code. You will find here guidance on how to [create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Right, so how many things are in `img_names`? Try a for loop printing anything you have in the list?

Comment: I changed the code to below:img_names = fetch_files('./*')
imgname = img_names[25]
for imgname in img_names:
    print(imgname)                                                                                                           again the same error

Comment: there are 25 folders each has 2 images